# Resize Canvas while maintaing the canvas ratio 3:2

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that I'm trying to make responsive. I've fiddled around and found a solution to make it responsive but now the problem is to maintain the aspect ratio. Canvas width is 600 and height is 400, so ratio is 3:2.

I'm using this:

```
<div id="container">


    <div id="main" role="main">
        <canvas id="respondCanvas" width="600" height="400">
            <!-- Provide fallback -->
        </canvas>
    </div>

</div> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready( function(){

        //Get the canvas & context
        var c = $('#respondCanvas');
        var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
        var container = $(c).parent();

        //Run function when browser  resize
        $(window).resize( respondCanvas );

        function respondCanvas(){
            c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
            c.attr('height', $(container).height() ); //max height

            //Redraw & reposition content
            var x = c.width();
            var y = c.height();             
            ct.font = "20px Calibri";

            ct.fillStyle = "#DDDDDD"; //black
            ct.fillRect( 0, 0, x, y); //fill the canvas

            var resizeText = "Canvas width: "+c.width()+"px";
            ct.textAlign = "center";
            ct.fillStyle = "#333333"; //white
            ct.fillText(resizeText, (x/2), (y/2) );
        }

        //Initial call
        respondCanvas();
    });


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys for your support, but there was very little required with that existing script.

```
function respondCanvas(){
        c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
        c.attr('height', $(container).width() / 1.5 ); //max height
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to keep the ratio is to replace the canvas with a img tag,
and set the img src with the canvas data:

```
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Add a style:

```
.the-img{max-width:100%}
```

to the img, then the img will resize with its parent container by keeping the ratio.

If you must use canvas, you can redraw the canvas with new_height/new_width=ratio:

for example:

```
new_width = x, 
new_height = pre_height/pre_width * x
```